# Use preg_match to find word in URL (or string with no spaces)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Sorry I'm kinda new to regex, anyways I have a url like `http://example.com/test/folder/?get=ThisisaValue` and I need it to return whether the word "get" is in there or not.

Whenever I run the function I get no match? Any help is appreciated thank you.

Sample code, let's say `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is `http://example.com/hello/?state=12345`

```
if(preg_match("state", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
   echo "match";
} else {
   echo "no match";
}
```

Comment: sorry I just meant the function preg_match. essentially my code is:

`preg_match("get", "http://example.com/test/folder/?get=ThisisaValue")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need it to return whether the word "get" is in there or not

In that case you don't need to match anything - you can just check for whether the substring is in the string, using `strpos()`.

```
if (strpos($url, 'get')) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are forgetting the delimiters:

```
preg_match("~state~", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

now it should work :)